# Updating Redux state by calling dispatch not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I have a redux that handles Authentication the responses are only access & refresh tokens, which the access token is sent as an authorization header, and if it has expired the refresh token is sent to get a new access token.

**this is the login Apicall**

```
 export const login = (dispatch, user) => {
        dispatch(loginStart());
        axiosInstance
            .post('users/login/', user)
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch(loginFailure(error.response.data.error));
            });
    };
```

**this is the logic used to send over the refresh token to get a new access token**

```
const refreshToken = currentUser?.refresh;

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('users/login/refresh/',  {
                            refresh: refreshToken,
                        })
                        .then((response, dispatch) => {
                            dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err, dispatch) => {
                            console.log(err);
                            dispatch(loginFailure());
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    <Navigate to="/login" />;
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                <Navigate to="/login" />;
            }
```

**this is the userSlice**

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        currentUser: null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
        errorMsg: null,
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
            state.errorMsg = action.payload
        },
    },
});
```

**added the main part of the redux store**

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: "user",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  blackList: [ 'errorMsg' ]
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userSlice });

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

for some reason that i don't know this causes an infinite loop or something that makes it call the api for ever.

[image]

Comment: If the first snippet is supposed to be a thunk, you need to change it to be a function that returns a function: `export const login = (user) => (dispatch) => { ... }`.

In the second snippet I can't see where you're dispatching the `login` action? Also, this seems to be a mixture of JSX and redux action somehow?

Comment: the login workes correctly and saves the access and refresh token to the local storage, but the second snippet in `.then((response, dispatch) => {
                            dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));` i though was supposed to take the response.data which are the access and refresh token and update the current one with it.

Comment: You're not showing any code that uses localStorage and we don't know what your global redux state looks like. Again, if your first snippet is a thunk - it is not in the correct format.

Comment: edited in the rest of the code, sorry not gud at this.

Comment: and I don't think I'm using the thing called a thunk, it's just passing the data to the store